# Get keyboard size without UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I want to get the size of the keyboard without using the keyboard notifications available. The reason is I have several text field on the view and I don't need to resize the view for **all** of them, as I have seen in nearly every example. I just need to resize the view for some of the text fields/views that will be **behind** the keyboard when editing. So I'm using `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and 
`textFieldDidEndEditing` methods, because here I know what textfield is being edited. Another problem is that even if I subscribe to the keyboard notifications the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is fired after `textFieldDidBeginEditing` so I cannot get the keyboard size on the first activation. I assume no information is provided from the keyboard notification functions where the actual text field or view is abailable.

```
The following code works but I need the keyboard size:

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField {
  if ([theControls containsObject: textField]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"szar" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, 0, -216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField {
  if ([theControls containsObject: textField]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"szar" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, 0, +216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get height of iOS keyboard without displaying keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981261/get-height-of-ios-keyboard-without-displaying-keyboard)

Comment: @DuncanBabbage in case it matters: wasn't that question asked 3 years later than mine? in case it doesn't: yes it is

Comment: Yes, yours posted first. The purpose of marking duplicates is to link together qs & de-duplicate to help users find high quality answers. The other q had a brief solution that worked. After working through the problem I wrote a high quality answer there to help future people facing this problem. Found your question afterwards, so marked it & several others as duplicates. Criteria is best answer to direct people to, not first posted. In this case, q didn't receive any working answers. I built on answer to the other q, so I would posted there regardless. Doesn't reflect negatively on you!

Answer (score 15):

I still used Notifications but not the ones you specified against. Maybe this will work better? Just trying to help, I understand how frustrating these things can be.

```
viewDidLoad {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                       object:nil];
 //For Later Use
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                       object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // Get the size of the keyboard.
  CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}
```

**Edit: This May Help As Well To Distinguish Active Text Fields From The Non-Active**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
self.activeTextField = textField;
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
self.activeTextField = nil;
}
```

Comment: keyboardWasShown called before 2 above textfield delegate