# Get Keyboard size without showing it

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, keyboard, autolayout

I can get the keyboard's dimension after its displayed from the notification, BUT I would like to position my textFields so that I don't have to scroll them when the keyboard appears. To achieve this I should know the keyboard's dimension BEFORE it's even displayed.

Is this possible on iOS?

Comment: You mean that text field are hidden behind keyboard. Then you scroll them so that the hidden text fields come up and be visible

Comment: Nope.  Until the "keyboardWillShow" event gets called, you won't know the keyboard's size.  And don't use hard-coded values for the keyboard height, it won't work...!   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284321/what-is-the-height-of-iphones-onscreen-keyboard/27798712#27798712

Comment: Please add screen shot, it's help to clarify your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get height of iOS keyboard before a keyboard is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981261/get-height-of-ios-keyboard-before-a-keyboard-is-displayed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class where this all things are handled by default. Just you have to use scroll view for this.

[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

See if it's useful and fulfill your requirement.

Comment: If you just need keyboard size, either you need to hard code it or use keyboardWillShow notification.There is no other way