# Get Keyboard frame without keyboardWillAppear userinfo notification, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am developing an iPhone app in which I have to show some customize picker in case of a button event. But I don't want to hard coded values for the frame of my custom pickerView. I searched and found `keyboardWillShow` notification userInfo method, but in my case I am not showing keyboard so can't get frame out of it. Can anybody help me way out for getting keyboard frame that I can use for my customize picker?

Comment: What? You can't. You want your pickerView to have the same frame as the keyboard without ever showing the keyboard.. Then make your pickerView the same height as the keyboard and width as the screen. You will have to hardcode the constraint constant or frame height constant.

Comment: What for? I agree with Brandon, you can just hardcode CGRect exactly matching keyboard frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get height of iOS keyboard without displaying keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981261/get-height-of-ios-keyboard-without-displaying-keyboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `UITextField` and call `becomeFirstResponder` and immediately `resignFirstResponder` on it, so it will be shown and hidden without actually seeing the keyboard.

the action method of the button will look like the following:

```
@IBAction func showPickerView(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let textField = UITextField()
    view.addSubview(textField)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

And you could listen to the notification and get the height.

for further information: [Get height of iOS keyboard without UIKeyboardWillShowNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981261/get-height-of-ios-keyboard-without-uikeyboardwillshownotification)