# How can I get height of Keyboard at starting of Application in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikeyboard

I created one Chat Board Application. But I need height of Keyboard at the starting of Application before any functions loads. I tried the Following one...

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

and after this I added this Function in My Code... It will return the Keyboard Hight but after the textFieldDidBeginEditing methods loads

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
}
```

---

The textFieldDidBeginEditing Method Look like this one

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.50) {

        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.textFieldBody.bounds.height + self.keyboardHeight;
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

But this will not provide me the values at starting point!

Comment: So do you want to know the keyboard height before even the keyboard showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get height of iOS keyboard without displaying keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981261/get-height-of-ios-keyboard-without-displaying-keyboard)